# div center of div while there another two divs

Tags: html, css

I have three divs in one div, one of them is at right, another of them is at left and i want to put third one at center but couldn't do it;

```html
<div id="durum3" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 40px);">
  <div class="processes" style="width: 100%; height: 40%; max-height: 84px; border-bottom:2px solid #9d7db1; min-height: 64px; min-width: 240px;max-width: 360px">
    <div id="firmalar" style="height: 100%; background: red; width: 74px;float: left "></div>

    <div id="islemler" style="height: 100%; background: yellow; width: 74px; text-align: center;  float: left; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
    <div id="pin" style="height: 100%; background: blue; width: 74px; float: right;margin-left: 5px "></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It should work if you remover the `float: left` from islemler. It's a good idea to try to avoid all floats if possible as they remove the elements from the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Flexbox and you don't even need to put `height`:

```html
<div style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px;">
  <div style="display: flex; height: 250px;">
    <div style="background-color: #99f; width: 25%"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #9f9; width: 50%"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #f99; width: 25%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```